# Python numpy arrays - initializing first element?

Tags: python, numpy

```
diffs = np.empty([2, 3]) # 2D array 2x3.
alldiffs = np.empty([2, 3, 1]) # 3D array 2x3xN. This creates 1st element. 

for x in range(1000): 
    diffs = new_diffs(x)
    alldiffs = np.dstack((alldiffs, diffs))
```

I end up with 1001 `diffs` elements in `alldiffs` - instead of 1000. How would I initialize `alldiffs` without first element being automatically created?

Comment: post the expected output, it'd be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating `alldiffs` as an empty array, create it in the first time you have the data in `diffs` with:

```
alldiffs = np.expand_dims(diffs, axis=2)
alldiffs = np.dstack((alldiffs, diffs))
alldiffs = np.dstack((alldiffs, diffs))
alldiffs.shape # (2, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Since I have `np.dstack` in the loop, this solution would require a conditional inside a loop, which seems like not a nice solution.

Comment: @Danijel I don't see a loop anywhere in the question. But anyway, if you found a better way than mine, everything's great.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't find a way. I still carry this first element around, which is a shame. Let me edit the question to include a loop.